# How to get speech data?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, speech-recognition

In my program, I can the lexicons, text, words and much more using the users voice. But, is there any way of getting the pitch of user's voice? I am using windows speech API with c#.

Following is the part of the code which I am using to get the voice data

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Speech.Recognition;
using System.Speech.Synthesis;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace Speech_Recognizer
{
    public class RecognizeSpeech
    {
        private SpeechRecognitionEngine sEngine; //Speech recognition engine
        private SpeechSynthesizer sSpeak; //Speech synthesizer
        string text3 = "";

        public RecognizeSpeech()
        {
            //Make the recognizer ready
            sEngine = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"));


            //Load grammar
            Choices sentences = new Choices();
            sentences.Add(new string[] { "I am hungry" });

            GrammarBuilder gBuilder = new GrammarBuilder(sentences);

            Grammar g = new Grammar(gBuilder);

            sEngine.LoadGrammar(g);

            //Add a handler
            sEngine.SpeechRecognized +=new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(sEngine_SpeechRecognized);


            sSpeak = new SpeechSynthesizer();
            sSpeak.Rate = -2;



            //Computer speaks the words to get the phones
            Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
            sSpeak.SetOutputToWaveStream(stream);


            sSpeak.Speak("I was hungry");
            stream.Position = 0;
            sSpeak.SetOutputToNull();


            //Configure the recognizer to stream
            sEngine.SetInputToWaveStream(stream);

            sEngine.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Single);


        }


        //Start the speech recognition task
        private void sEngine_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
        {
            string text = "";

            if (e.Result.Text == "I am hungry")
            {
                foreach (RecognizedWordUnit wordUnit in e.Result.Words)
                {
                    text = text + wordUnit.Pronunciation + "\n";
                }

                MessageBox.Show(e.Result.Text + "\n" + text);
            }


        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, `SpeechSynthesizer` can set and get speech rate, sound etc. how to get pitch from user's speech? any oter info I can take?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the Microsoft SR engine does not return pitch data from the user's voice.

Comment: After a long time, I have a reply. Thank you a lot :)